# CSS width 100% within margins for textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, textarea

I want a `<textarea>` to have 100% height and width taking any margin/padding into account.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MaxKielland/dNVJ8/1/) and as you can see, the `<textarea>` seems to include the margins.

Comment: The fiddle does not look good in Chrome, the `<textarea>` actually goes out of the border.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this in textarea css : `box-sizing: border-box;`

Comment: This will not account for `margin`, only for `padding`, though.

Comment: I added this to the textarea CSS and boom, it worked great, even when resizing the dialogue.

Answer (score 1):

I would propose using this code on top of your css file:

```
/* apply a natural box layout model to all elements */
*, *:before, *:after {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

It should make using css sizing a lot more comfortable for your. See [this edited jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9t2Y6/) to get an idea of how it works.

For further reference and information read [this article](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/).

Comment: Interesting article and the fiddle looks great until I drag and resize the window, then the textarea pops out again.